# Checking for duplicates using includes/indexOf doesnt work in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to look for duplicate from a range (array) of new data and flag them into the spreadsheet as duplicate when it an existing data is available from another range.

However, my problem is that the conditions where the new data is compared to the existing list of data is not working. I used indexOf and includes function to no avail.

New data example (printed from the Logger):

```
joNumRangeUploader:
77324,77320,77318,77341,77302,77267,76975,76576
```

Existing list example data (printed from the Logger):

```
joNumRangeMMICS:
77123,77002,77020,77037,77041,77042,77125,75861,74869,74960,75971,76608,76508,77287,75192,75751,75397,75715,76609,76610,74910,74814,77158,75484,76358,75984,75932,75931,76940,76444,76682,76970,76910,76459,76974,76975,76576,
```

**Expected result:**

**76975,76576** should both be flagged as duplicates

**Actual result:**

But, then again, they are not flagged nor the condition with includes() work.

Below is my code:

```
//get values into array
const joNumRangeUploader = uploaderSheet.getRange(UploaderFirstDataRow,joNumColUploader,uploaderRowCount,1).getValues();
const joNumRangeMMICS    = mmicsSheet.getRange(2,joNumColSource,mmicsSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
const joNumRangeBAU      = bauSheet.getRange(2,joNumColSource,bauSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();

let uniqueDataArray = new Array();

//go through joNumRangeUploader array and check for a duplicate; write to cell if duplicate
for(i=0; i < joNumRangeUploader.length; i++){
    const dataToCheck = joNumRangeUploader[i][0];
    let isUnique = true;

    let fileSource = '';
    //look for duplicates compating the dataToCheck to the 2 other indices
    if(joNumRangeMMICS.includes(dataToCheck)){
      fileSource = 'MMICS';
      isUnique = false;
      ui.alert("Duplicate found!");   //doesnt show in actual
    }
    else if(joNumRangeBAU.includes(dataToCheck) && isUnique === true){
      fileSource = 'MASTERFILE';
      isUnique = false;
      ui.alert("Duplicate found!");   //doesnt show in actual
    }

    if (isUnique==true){
      const pushRange = uploaderSheet.getRange((i+UploaderFirstDataRow),firstColUpload, 1, sourceColCount);
      //push upload range to array
      uniqueDataArray.push(pushRange.getValue());
      //expected: Lx:ANx
    }
    else{
      uploaderSheet.getRange( (i+UploaderFirstDataRow), statusCol, 1, 1).setValue("DUPLICATE " + fileSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: any reason you're using apps script instead of formulas or conditional formatting?

Comment: well that could be one option. I havent done that yet but will try it. 
to answer your question, the main reason is that an external google sheet is involved.

Comment: I see you already found another solution, but I think the original issue is that both `joNumRangeUploader` and `joNumRangeMMICS` are 2D arrays, and you're treating them as simple arrays (actually you were treating `joNumRangeUploader` correctly, but removed the second index `[i][0]` because of an advice from another answer - you shouldn't have don that). In any case, if you add `flat()` when declaring these two arrays (e.g. `const joNumRangeUploader = uploaderSheet.getRange(UploaderFirstDataRow,joNumColUploader,uploaderRowCount,1).getValues().flat()`) your problem should be solved.

Comment: Would this solution be useful to you? In that case I'd post an answer explaining this.

Comment: Hi! This works!!!!! Flattening the array would have been the initial solution. However, I kinda liked the simplicity of doing a formula to lessen the performance workload in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I'm posting the solution to your original problem (cannot find duplicates between two arrays), even though you found a workaround via formulas.

#### Issue:

Both `joNumRangeUploader` and `joNumRangeMMICS` are 2D arrays (that's what [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns), and you're treating them as simple arrays.

#### Solution:

Use [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) after calling `getValues()` to get simple arrays instead:

```
const joNumRangeUploader = uploaderSheet.getRange(UploaderFirstDataRow,joNumColUploader,uploaderRowCount,1).getValues().flat();
const joNumRangeMMICS    = mmicsSheet.getRange(2,joNumColSource,mmicsSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you declare `dataToCheck` you set it as `joNumRangeUploader[i][0]`, instead you should set it as `joNumRangeUploader[i]`,You're trying to access the first element in an integer wich will return `NaN`, wich doesn't exist in `joNumRangeMMICS` or `joNumRangeBAU`

Comment: I removed + and [0] but it still doesnt work.

From what I know, a single column range in Google sheets has an array like this [ [ ],[ ],[ ],[ ],[ ]...]

Comment: that's not what you said in the question but.. you can try to console.log(dataToCheck) to make sure what its actual value is

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: (The original script)**

Thanks to @Iamblichus, flattening the exisiting list array did the job since getValues() always create a 2D array.

Sample code:

```
joNumRangeUploader = uploaderSheet.getRange(UploaderFirstDataRow,joNumColUploader,uploaderRowCount,1).getValues().flat()
```

**Alternative:**

I have made it work thanks to @Dmitry Kostyuk's suggestion to include formula. I created a separate sheet with a query from an external SS and referenced the formula to that sheet within the same spreadsheet.

Formula used is:

```
=IF(IFNA(match($B13,Query!B:B,0),0)>0,"DUPLICATE FOUND","")
```

[image]

Then to filter the row that does NOT include "DUPLICATE FOUND", I used the code below and put it into another array.

```
const uniqueDataArray = uploadRange.filter((data,i) => {
      return duplicateStatusRangeData[i][0].includes("DUPLICATE FOUND")===false;
    });
```

Note that **duplicateStatusRangeData[i] !== "DUPLICATE FOUND"** does NOT work due to how the Google sheets getValues() function create its array for a single column which is 2D, [ [ ], [ ], [ ], ... ].